# Ubuntu 16.04 mesa 32 bit libraries removal

Tags: nvidia, package-management, 32-bit, mesa

I'm having lots of troubles with 32-bit libraries being used in various programs. After a lot of searching I found a question on here that said that the mesa directories could be causing it and to remove them and run "ldconfig" to update it. When I did all my programs that were previously not working started working without issues. I'm using Nvidia so I suppose it's something to do with that. Anyways, everytime my computer updates it reinstalls all the mesa libraries I just deleted. I tried running "sudo apt-get remove ..." but then it lists all the packages that will be removed and it's almost everything in my computer. So I cancel the removal. Is there any way I can remove these mesa libraries permanently without breaking my OS?

Below is the command I have to run to see where the files I need to remove are located:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-396/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-396/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-396/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-396/libGL.so
```

And after I delete the files located in the .../mesa/ directory I run:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-396/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-396/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-396/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-396/libGL.so
```