# Resolution 640x480 with nvidia-driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

My Ubuntu 18.04 is unstable with nouveau (slow and [crashes when I open system settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049288/ubuntu-18-04-opening-system-setting-logs-me-out)).

So I installed the Nvidia proprietary driver (I tried each one from nvidia-driver-390 to nvidia-driver-470) but at reboot I get only the [640x480 resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484258/resolution-640x480-after-installing-nvidia-display-and-cuda-drivers-for-gtx-750) without being able to change it (and the Nvidia control panel is empty).

I tried to purge all the nvidia stuff (`sudo apt purge *nvidia*`), I deleted `xorg.conf` and the I tried manually forcing the desired resolution... nothing works.

It used to work (with nvidia-driver-460), then I moved my Ubuntu install to a machine with integrated Intel graphics, when I moved back to the previous machine with the Nvidia GPU this issue appeared.

This is some information about my setup:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:68 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:c0000-dfff

$ sudo inxi -F -x
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] bus-ID: 3b:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.20.8 drivers: fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 2560x1440@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 Direct Render: Yes

$ ubuntu-drivers devices
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:3b:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001043sd0000863Ebc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Edit: I found that for some reason my system is using llvmpipe somehow related to VMware (that I had installed, but now is not installed anymore).

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 20.0.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 32084MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "moving the install"?

Comment: I installed it on a drive on the PC with the Nvidia GPU, then for a while I used it on a Laptop with Intel integrated graphics, now I'm back on the PC with the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: That's not specific enough. Did you clone the install and copy it to another computer? Swap the hard drive? Install fresh?

Comment: To me it was clear that I moved the drive, but what's the difference anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the info! It might be clear to you, but you are not the one you are asking for help. Keep in mind that everyone here is volunteering their time, and showing attitude is not a good way to get help.

Comment: is this a install in vmware? `Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)`

Comment: @nobody: no, it's not running in a VM (and has never been)

Comment: llvmpipe is part of the Mesa drivers that were used when your hard drive was installed in the machine with Intel graphics. The question is really how to stop using Mesa in favor of Nvidia. This question doesn't have an answer, but it claims to be able to at least temporarily stop Mesa and use Nvidia. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030471/ubuntu-16-04-mesa-32-bit-libraries-removal